# iOS SwiftUI Form onTapGesture blocks child user interface functionality

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

the Form view seems to create troubles using the newest SwiftUI (I'm new to it and haven't tested it in older version tbh).

The simple code executes the `onTapGesture` function correctly when clicking on the button, although it disables all the user feedback (so not visual change in the button on pressing, hold and release) and also does not execute the button action anymore:

```
var body: some View 
{
    Form 
    {
        Button(action: {
            print("button action")
        }) 
        {
            Text("Button")
        }
        .onTapGesture 
        {
            print("tap button")
        }
    }
    .onTapGesture 
    {
        print("tap form")
    }    
}
```

When exchanging `Form` with `HStack` the visual feedback and console prints work. So it definitely seems to be an issue with the Form view.

When commenting the `onTapGesture` Form function the button feedback works again. So only the onTapGesture on the Form blocks all child interaction.

Does anyone know what this is - and is there a workaround?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Catch Tap gesture on Form in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58433473/catch-tap-gesture-on-form-in-swiftui)

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58433473/catch-tap-gesture-on-form-in-swiftui the issue is the button action is blocking the "Tap button" gesture

Comment: Not really, as it solves not the main problem that adding the onTapGesture causes all child elements of the Form disable their tap behaviour.

Without the onTapGesture the child button will not respond to taps anymore (only long taps).
When added the onLongTapGesture, the child button does not respond to any tapping anymore.

Even using:
`.gesture(TapGesture().onEnded{ print("tapped")}, including: .all)`

which should also enable the children objects to execute their tap behaviour, does not work.

Comment: why do you need a tapgesture on a button? thats a very poor design

Comment: The button tap is just an example. Also without the onTapGesture the Button's visual feedback won't work as soon as the Form as an onTapGesture function attached.